# Start Service exactly at start of hour and repeat every hour afterwards

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

I'm looking to start a IntentService at the start of every hour repeating exactly on the hour (1:00PM, 2:00PM, 3:00PM, etc.).

Having looked at the documentation, I believe using AlarmManager to do this is the best practice.

I have a BootReceiver which will start the application for the first instance and below in my onHandleIntent the next alarm is set after the task has been repeated(For example vibration below). My problem is that I am unable to set the alarm to go off at the top of the next hour, how would I go about this?

For testing I have the alarm going off every 3 minutes in the code below

```
public class TimingAndControl extends IntentService
{ public TimingAndControl()
{
super(TimingAndControl.class.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{  
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |       PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "VibrateTag");
  wakeLock.acquire();

  Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

  v.vibrate(300);

  NextAlarm();
}

private void NextAlarm()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// The update frequency should often be user configurable.  This is not.

long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + 3 * (60 * 1000);
Time nextUpdateTime = new Time();
nextUpdateTime.set(nextUpdateTimeMillis);

if (nextUpdateTime.hour < 6 || nextUpdateTime.hour >= 18)
{
  nextUpdateTime.hour = 8;
  nextUpdateTime.minute = 0;
  nextUpdateTime.second = 0;
  nextUpdateTimeMillis = nextUpdateTime.toMillis(false) + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
}
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pendingIntent);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", (10 * 1000)).show();
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  Toast.makeText(this, "service stopping", (10 * 1000)).show();
  super.onDestroy();
} 



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that I am unable to set the alarm to go off at the top of the next hour, how would I go about this?

Calculate when the top of the next hour is, then use that as the second parameter to `setRepeating()` on `AlarmManager`.

Comment: The service needs to fire exactly on the top of every hour, would I be able to maintain the accuracy I need by doing this. Also how would I go about calculating when the next top of hour is, would I be best off setting the next alarm at say 12:00PM and repeating the alarm from there on? Apologies, I'm finding AlarmManager very difficult to get to grips with

Comment: @user1001160: "would I be able to maintain the accuracy I need by doing this" -- it will be reasonably accurate, if you use `RTC_WAKEUP` or `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`. That being said, Android is not a RTOS, and clocks drift, etc. "Also how would I go about calculating when the next top of hour is" -- use `java.util.Calendar`, as this is ordinary Java, nothing unique to Android. " would I be best off setting the next alarm at say 12:00PM and repeating the alarm from there on?" -- I would certainly use `setRepeating()` for this scenario.

Comment: Great, think I have it figured out. Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried RTC_WAKEUP , RTC flag will trigger alarm only after the device wakes from Sleep .

Answer (score 0):

You can find the UTC millisecond time of next hour with code like this (not tested)

```
public static final long utcMillisNextHour() {
    Time t = new Time();
    t.setToNow();
    t.hour++;
    t.minute = 0;
    t.second = 0;
    return t.normalize(true);
}
```

Then you can use one of the setReapting..() method of AlarmManager with time type that accepts UTC time and a INTERVAL_HOUR interval. If the intent you are sending is fixed, not harm in calling it multiple time as each setRepeating() will delete the previous ones.